# SCNScene load from DAE error

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I'm loading an `SCNScene` from a DAE file in an iOS app like this:

```
sceneView?.scene = SCNScene(named: "MYSCENE.dae")
```

At first it was loading the scene without any of the textures (the scene was made using Modo and exported to DAE) so I cleaned the project and reimported the DAE file and now it's giving me the following error:

> MTLTextureDescriptor has one or more dimensions set that are zero or greater than the maximum allowed size.

Followed by a crash.

What exactly does this error mean? And how can I resolve it?

Comment: Without your DAE file I think it is not possible to tell you what is wrong.